# What did David Cameron mean by describing his speeches as "Hello birds, Hello trees"?

Tags: united-kingdom

In the Guardian interview, "['Some people I will never convince': Cameron reflects on his Brexit legacy](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/sep/20/some-people-never-convince-david-cameron-reflects-brexit-legacy)" by Martin Kettle, it states that David Cameron...

> ...admits that “some of the early speeches were a bit ‘Hello birds.
>   Hello trees.’”

Though I get that this might be some kind of Monty Python reference, I'm still unsure of what it was actually supposed to mean. It seems to have some clever nuance which I am not getting.

Comment: It's a line from [Life of Brian](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=life-of-brian).

Comment: It also evokes Molesworth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotherington-Tomas

Answer (score 2):

An older snippet in the Telegraph says:

> Cameron did not rise to the very top of British politics by skipping through life like [Fotherington-Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotherington-Tomas) saying “hello birds, hello trees”.

So the implication/reading (of the more recent quote) seems to be that his early speeches were "effeminate" (an essential characteristic of the Fotherington-Thomas character), most likely in the sense of lacking strong[er] messages.

Somewhat similarly, but in more detail, the Evening Standard says

> For most of the country, quite reasonably worried about inflation, spending cuts and unemployment, this abstruse project has the whiff of what Bagehot called "London business": the sort of silly, irrelevant scheme that we inhabitants of the capital dream up in moments of self-indulgence. "I worry that all the Big Society and Lib-Dem liberty and electoral reform stuff looks fluffy and out of touch," says one senior Government source. "It's all a bit 'hello birds, hello trees' when the public are having a seriously bad time of it." When the patient is undergoing open heart surgery, you don't interrupt to ask if he would prefer Assam or builder's tea.

This seems to be a more direct link to what Cameron said, i.e. it's probably a reference to his [Big Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Society) speeches being perceived as out-of-touch with contemporary problems.

Comment: Did Fotherington-Thomas actually ever say "*Hello birds.  Hello trees.*"?  If not, the reference seems more likely from [Life of Brian - funniest moment - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDFZflAfhy0), in which a character talks incessantly just for the joy of talking, without actually saying anything meaningful.